# Hankel transform

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

The Hankel transform of $f=h(a-r)$ and $g=1/\sqrt{r^2+b^2}$ are $a/s\,J_{1}(as)$ and $e^{-bs}/s$ respectively. Here, h is a Heaviside side function that is 0 if $r>a$ and $1$ otherwise. a and b are some constants values. The Hankel transform is defined as $H(f) = \int\limits_0^\infty  {f(r)\,r\,{J_0}(sr)\,dr}$.

I am trying to find an expression for the Hankel transform of product of two functions $H(fg)$. I would be grateful to hear your suggestion and helps. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is a convolution theorem for Hankel transforms: to get $H(fg)$ convolve $(Hf)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ with $(Hg)(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and then in the answer replace $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by $s$; having said that, your choice of $f$ and $g$ does not seem to produce a closed-form answer.

Comment: @Carlo thanks for your response, that what I was thinking to perform double convolution integral f**g but I could not proceed to obtain a closed form solution.